# Change [velodyne] frame for gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, lidar, gmapping, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have .pcap file collected from VLP16 and I first run

```
roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP16_points.launch pcap:=/home/soowon/Documents/111.pcap
```

I can now see in RVIZ in fixed frame of [velodyne]

Then I use

```
rosrun pointcloud_to_laserscan pointcloud_to_laserscan_node cloud_in:=/velodyne_points
```

to convert to 2d laser scan.

and then record it as rosbag file.

But when I want to combine it with laser_scan_matcher and gmapping, the frame is always not correct.

I searched online and it seems that I should reset frame_id when doing the first step. But I don't know what to do in detail.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255443/change-%5Bvelodyne%5D-frame-for-gmapping/) by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2017-02-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nxydes](https://answers.ros.org/users/23306/nxydes/) on 2017-02-23**:
Does your robot model currently have a frame for velodyne and its just under a different name? If you aren't publishing a frame for the velodyne it simply won't work and I highly suggest publishing a velodyne frame before changing the name. http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-23**:
@nxydes I'm not using a robot. Thats why I want to use laser_scan_matcher to get tf from /map to /base_link I dont know what should I do in this case. Can you tell me?

**Comment by [nxydes](https://answers.ros.org/users/23306/nxydes/) on 2017-02-23**:
Try this then, publish a static transform from base_link to velodyne of all 0's. Will effectively make velodyne frame the same as base_link:
rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link velodyne

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-23**:
@nxydes Thanks, I will try

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-24**:
@nxydes It works, but the tf has some problem. It has two branches:

1. map->odom
2. map->base_link->velodyne
   Generally there should only be one line, right?

**Comment by [nxydes](https://answers.ros.org/users/23306/nxydes/) on 2017-02-24**:
Seems that laser scan matcher is publishing map->base_link. You need to set its "world frame" to be odom so it publishes odom-> baselink.
See 4.3.1: http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-24**:
@nxydes Oh, you are really helpful. If you want, you can write a formal answer and I will choose yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publish a tf for base_link -> velodyne via either robot state publisher or just a simple tf broadcaster

```
 rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link velodyne
```

Make sure you set laser scan matcher "world frame" to be odom as in section 4.3.1 in http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher

Now gmapping will provide map -> odom

Laser scan matcher will provide odom -> base_link

Utilizing the static base_link -> velodyne

---

Originally posted by [nxydes](https://answers.ros.org/users/23306/nxydes/) with karma: 81 on 2017-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3